# Cant checkout to certain branches on sourcetree

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I have 2 branches in git project which are impossible to checkout to. I get this error:
[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omvjd.png)

There are dozens other branches which I am capable of checking out to, but this one produces error.
How do I fix that?
Thanks

Comment: It’s the backslash.

Comment: How to fix that?